# Facebook JS SDK - Login Button Integration

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have this basic HTML page with a Facebook login button. The ID below is the ID of an app I created in my developer portal. When I run this page, it only shows the text “Login with Facebook” and not the actual button. I know it’s not succeeding to initialize the SDK but I can’t tell what is going on. Any ideas?

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '232894623452511',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems to work.  See example of your code running here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/HXRUv/3/

Comment: can you please tell me how to redirect to localhost after successful login?

Comment: @Anoopss Golden Refer to section 3 of this doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/ and insert code: window.location.href='http://localhost/'; in the branch of "connected successfully".

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your browser plugins. My Chrome is only displaying text, but it has do not track me plugin, Firefox works fine.