# html5 facebook like button not working in local

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

I write code to insert FB like button using configurator wizard by facebook developer page.

Both code (HTML5 and IFrame) work properly in remote but in local only IFrame works properly, HTML5 button doesn't shown.
Do you know what's the problem?
Thanks

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<br>
TEST LIKE HTML5
<br>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.karimrashid.com/" data-send="false"   data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
<br>
TEST LIKE IFRAME
<br>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F %2Fwww.karimrashid.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;action=like&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work if you host it remotely?

Comment: Probably [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Does either Chrome dev tools or Firebug show any errors?

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat yes it works but I need it works in local too

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post if it helps

[Facebook JS SDK - Login Button Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771640/facebook-js-sdk-login-button-integration)

Don't you need to do FB.Init before you can use this script?

Comment: no i didn't. I can try, but which value I have to put in appId? I haven't created app, is it necessary?

Comment: I think it's necssary. It's very easy to create one. Just takes minutes

Comment: it doesn't work. however appId is optional [FB.init](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)

Comment: I try to add http: before //connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1 and the result is blank row to allocate something that I don't see.

Comment: dont think it works with localhost. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292850/unable-to-test-facebook-like-button-on-localhost-unlike-before

Also tried your code with jsfiddle and it looks fine so nothing wrong with the code